# Read pixel color directly from a byte array where image dimensions are known

Tags: .net, image, arrays, pixel

I download PNG images of dimensions 256 x 256 as bytes array using webclient.

I need to detect just the pixel colours at a specific location (0,0) to determine processing instructions for each downloaded image.

Presently I convert the bytes to memory stream then convert into a bitmap.

Next I use GetPixel(0,0) to get the required pixel information.

This method is not only slow, but involves too many steps.

I already have the imageArray direct from the webclient dowmloadData menthod.

Please how can I simply read the pixel value at location(0,0) or preferably at location(x,y) directly from the byte array.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmya, writing your own image decoder is something every programmer needs to do once to learn that it is never the appropriate solution.  You don't need our help, the source code for pnglib is [readily available](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngcode.html).

Comment: @HansPassant I really dont need a full PNG lib, just need to read the pixel at location(x,y) of a png byte array without going through several layers of .net code

Comment: Well, you do, PNG is pretty advanced image format.  You cannot skip the need to handle the different pixel formats it supports, properly locate the pixel data and use LZW decompression to decode at least part of it.   Of course you'll have many *more* layers.

Comment: @HansPassant Point taken. Thanks